# Trigger script on html form submit

Tags: php, html

I am writing a webpage with an upload feature that allows me to upload a file and run a script to act on uploaded file. I have the script working to act on a file, as well as the upload working to get the file in a specified folder. The script is python and I am using an HTML form with a PHP script for the file uploading. I just want to be able to watch the directory for changes then act on any changes that occur. I looked [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) but I would rather have a trigger on change immediately than poll the directory every X seconds.

The file upload script is basically a copy-paste of [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) and my python file takes in the file name as a command line argument and creates an output file in the same directory.

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments I tried triggering the python script with php `shell_exec()` and `exec()` but neither have been working. For testing purposes, I ran `chmod 777-R` on both the working directory and the directory with the input files I want to run and I get a return of `1` when running `is_null($output)` on my command when trying to run the script.

What's confusing me is when i run the command `ls /directory/to/work/from/` I get a return when I `echo $output` and `NULL` isn't returned. Why does `ls` work but my python script not?

I suppose I should add for clarification I have run the exact python script from my terminal and it works perfectly.

Comment: As proposed in the comment, why not just have the PHP file uploader call the python script?

Comment: Why can't you place the notification code (email, log entry etc) in the php and/or python code?

Comment: I am very new to PHP but I will try that. I didn't think to do that but it should work. Thanks!